# Pink pixels on left edge of display

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

With my Elecrow 7" touchscreen display, I noticed a 2 pixel column of just pink that is on the left edge of the screen. The mouse doesn't move onto the pink, and on the right side moves completely offscreen. This leads me to believe that this is a OS issue, and (hopefully) not a hardware one.
[image: image of pink column]

My display is 1024x600, if that makes a difference.

What on earth could be causing this?

Info: I have disabled overscan for more precision on the touchscreen

Answer (score 3):

After contacting the seller, I was told to add `hdmi_drive=1` to the end of `/boot/config.txt`. That fixed my issue. Hope this information help future users!